# HBase connection refused after random time delays

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, hadoop-yarn, apache-zookeeper

I have installed [Hadoop single node](http://intellitech.pro/tutorial-hadoop-first-lab/)  and [Hbase](http://intellitech.pro/hbase-installation-on-ubuntu/) successfully. I am using a Java agent to connect to the Hbase. After a random time period Hbase stop working and the java agent gives following error message.

> Call exception, tries=7, retries=7, started=8321 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=Call to db-2.c.xxx-dev.internal/xx.xx.0.21:16201 failed on connection exception: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: db-2.c.xxx-dev.internal/xx.xx.0.21:16201, details=row 'xxx,00000000001:1553904000000,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=db-2.c.xxx-dev.internal,16201,1553683263844, seqNum=-1

Here are the Hbase and zookeeper logs

hbase-hduser-regionserver-db-2.log

> [main] zookeeper.ZooKeeperMain: Processing delete
>   2019-03-30 02:11:44,089 DEBUG [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x169bd98c099006e, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 1,2  replyHeader:: 1,300964,0  request:: '/hbase/rs/db-2.c.stl-cardio-dev.internal%2C16201%2C1553683263844,-1  response:: null

hbase-hduser-zookeeper-db-2.log

> server.FinalRequestProcessor: sessionid:0x169bd98c099004a type:getChildren cxid:0x28e3ad zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:/hbase/splitWAL

my hbase-site.xml file is as follows

```
<configuration>
        //Here you have to set the path where you want HBase to store its files.
        <property>
           <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
           <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
           <value>localhost</value>
        </property>
       //Here you have to set the path where you want HBase to store its built in zookeeper  files.
        <property>
           <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
           <value>${hbase.tmp.dir}/zookeeper</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
           <value>2181</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

when I restart the Hbase it will start working again and stop working after few days. I am wondering what would be the fix for this.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way I am running this on a Google Cloud VM.